# What are MIR datasets?

Tags: dataset

What does MIR stand for?

e.g. http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/pages/additional-datasets and http://www.phenix-online.org/documentation/tutorial_mir.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the MIR acronym [varies according to the context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_%28disambiguation%29):

- The first link you provided probably relates to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_information_retrieval).
- The second one relates to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_isomorphous_replacement).

Comment: Thanks! In retrospect, I should have gone to wikipedia as a first port of call in this instance.